# When is a decay mediated by the weak force

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, standard-model

If a $\pi ^+ \to \nu_\mu+\mu^+$, here quark flavour is lost entirely. I am aware the weak force mediates decays where quark flavour is not conserved. But If I consider a $p+\bar p$ annihilating, here quark flavour is lost as well but the decay is not mediated by the weak force, but rather by photons (or the strong force?).

When do we use the w and z bosons in a decay?

Edit:

$u \bar d$ are the quarks we start with. We end with up with 0 quarks, losing all flavour, is this still a process mediated by the weak forces W bosons? I was initially under the impression that the products still had to contain quarks for a weak force decay.

Comment: Why do you think flavor is not conserved in $p\bar{p}$ annihilation?

Comment: Ah, the flavour is 0 before and after, but what about the first decay process? A hadron decays into a lepton, I can't see how flavour is conserved.

Comment: What is "the first decay process"?

Comment: In general, if you want to get your questions answered, you need to spell out all the reasoning you used to arrive at your conclusions.

Comment: @knzhou I have made an edit, sorry I was vague about that, by first decay I mean the pi+ decaying into leptons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One works with [feynman diagram](http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2002/feynman/examples.htm#Example%202)s to keep count of quantum numbers:

[image: p+ mu netrino]

Pions decay because they consist of a [quark and an antiquark](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html) and the $W^+$meson changes  the up into a down through the weak interaction, allowing down-antidown annihilation into a virtual $W^+$, and then the $W^+$ decays.